# Moving files from one directory and appending a date to the file name to another directory

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script as follows

```
move /Y E:\Scripts\*.sql E:\Scripts\OBIEE
```

Lets say in E:\Scripts I have a file insert.sql I want to save it in E:\Scripts\OBIEE
as insert_31102012.sql where 31102012 is the current date 31 Oct 2012.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will append the date (_YYYYMMDD) to all .SQL files in the E:\Scripts\ directory, then move them to the E:\Scripts\OBIEE\ subfolder.

```
@echo off
cd E:\Scripts\
set cur_yyyy=%date:~10,4%
set cur_mm=%date:~4,2%
set cur_dd=%date:~7,2%
for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.sql') do (
rename %%f %%~nf_%cur_yyyy%%cur_mm%%cur_dd%%%~xf
move %%~nf_%cur_yyyy%%cur_mm%%cur_dd%%%~xf ./OBIEE/
)
```

Comment: Thanks Rick. What if there is only one file?

Comment: If there is only one file in the \Scripts\ folder, it will still rename\move that one file.  If there are multiple SQL files, but you only intend to move one, you can change the "*.sql" to target the specific file (i.e. "Insert.sql")

Comment: ok, thanks alot. It worked at first but a second attempt produced an error : system cannot find the specified file. If I may ask, what is the /b for in the for /f %%f in ('dir /b *.sql')

Comment: From the help: "/B Uses bare format (no heading information or summary)".  So it makes sure you only get file names.  Run "dir /?" for full details.